# How do you delete a header completely from a request using groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to be able to do what the red x button does, but in a groovy script:

[image]

I tried the following script, but it looks like the empty strings only clear the header and its value, but not delete it:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap 

def headers = new StringToStringMap()
headers.put("","")
```

It seems like there is still a header according to the tab:

[image]

Looks like the error is in line 4

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of the test step is that?

Comment: @Rao it's a REST request step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below groovy script. All you need to do is provide the Rest Request test step's name in the below :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap    
//Define / change the step name for which headers to be removed.
def step = 'REST Request'
def nextRequest = context.testCase.testSteps[step]?.httpRequest
nextRequest?.requestHeaders = [:]
```

EDIT: based on OP's comments

Change from:

```
nextRequest?.requestHeaders = [:]
```

To

```
nextRequest?.requestHeaders = [:] as StringToStringMap
```

Comment: I get the following error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequest.setRequestHeaders() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[:]] Possible solutions: setRequestHeaders(com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringMap), setRequestHeaders(com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToStringsMap), getRequestHeaders() error at line: 4

Comment: line 4 has the following code: nextRequest?.requestHeaders = [:]

Comment: I can delete the headers successfully with the same code. would you mind showing the screen shot of your test case? and step with headers?

Comment: what is your soapui version?

Comment: I left the images above in another answer since I can't upload images to comments.

Comment: I'm using SoapUI NG Pro, which is part of ReadyAPI 1.8.0

Comment: not sure what you mean by test case screenshot, I added the overview of all the steps...hopes that help.

Comment: @JeffreyLee, glad that it helped. Just coercing to SoapUI's map type.