# Remove header from SoapUI request

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, soapui

I need to remove the Connection header from a REST srequest.
[image]

I'm using SoapUI (not ReadyAPI). All the suggested solutions I have found so far mention event handler which looks like it's only available in the paid version. Any help would be greatly appreciated. It seems strange that such rudimentary functionality, to set your own headers, is missing...

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I did try a solution from stackoverflow.com/a/44193464/3355860, using a standard Groovy step to no avail
[image]

Comment: See if this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44193464/3355860 or this https://community.smartbear.com/t5/ReadyAPI-Questions/Clearing-request-headers/m-p/43176/highlight/true#M23008

Comment: @ou_ryperd yeah tried those already. In the the first one the guy is using ReadyAPI. But I did try adding a Groovy step before my REST call. No affect on headers

The second one refers to the event handler, which is again ReadyAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default keep-alive with any value you want.  Including null, but I cannot find a way to remove it completely in SoapUI (free).

[image: override connection]

Which results in....
[image: overriden]